# generate data of mixed-effect model in R, especially the random-effect variables

Tags: r, logistic, mixed-model

I'm new to R.PLEASE help me for these simulation:
I have a **mixed-effect logistic model** with **fixed-effect** variables such as groups,english abilities,etc.,and two variables of **participants and materials as random-effect** ones.How can I generate an artificial data for this model in R? Besides,how can I generate data assuming there is a significant **correlation between two fixed-effect variables**?
Thanks.